# How do I change my navbar from "left to right" to "right to left"?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I built an English language web site, and now I'm working on the Arabic version.

How do I change the navigation bar to be displayed *right to left*?
I'm using the [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme 3.3.5.

Comment: Are you using the Bootstrap theme's default navbar(which has logo/site-name/menu-items/My-account/logout). Or you have navigation with just items?

Comment: yes i'm using the default one

Comment: Your need can be done using CSS ro nav-bar. But I think you should see also RLT bootstrap theme here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730598/right-to-left-support-for-twitter-bootstrap-3).

Comment: Since for D8 there is only a 3.0 release, and for D7 there is a 3.6 release (already), my best guess is that this question is about D7. However, to answer questions "I" do not like to guess about the release of Drupal. Please edit your question to avoid we have to guess ...

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** Following answer is for D7, but the concept is same for D8 also I think, if you want to do using CSS, Just you need to apply the same logic where to apply CSS `float: left;` and `float: right;`.

This you can do with CSS.

If there is just a menu with list of items, you can do easily with `float: right` at appropriate place.

But, **bootstrap's default** `nav-bar` contains `Logo` `Site name` `primary-menu` and `Secondary-menu`, Hence css will be some complicated.

Now, I have used the following set (**LTR** Default),

> [image]

And after looking their HTML I have applied following CSS,

```
.navbar {
    .navbar-header {float: right;
        a.logo { float: right !important;}
    }
    .navbar-collapse{
        nav {

            ul.menu.navbar-nav {float: right;
                li {
                    float: right;
                }
            }
            ul.menu.navbar-nav.secondary {float: left !important;
                li {
                    float: right;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

After applying the CSS, It has arranged in such a way.

> [image]

If you slightly practice, you can by yourself come to know how it works, it is easy.

Comment: I have the impression that this solution could work for either D7 or D8, am I right? I think you should add something about that (an extra "note" or so) to clarify that also ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Thanks for pointing out. This answer is for D7, I will add that one. Thanks again.